# .mht files display as junk text from Jetty server

Tags: server, webserver, configuration, java, content-type

I have some `.mht` files which load fine from local files but when loaded from the Jetty web server display as junk text.

What can I do to make them work correctly from my Jetty web server? I know that for Apache server I need to add the below lines of code to `.htaccess` file. But how do I make similar changes for Jetty? I am using IntelliJ as my IDE.

```
 <IfModule mod_mime.c> 
  # MIME HyperText Markup Language (MHTML) markup 
   AddType text/html .mhtml .mht .maff .maf 
  AddType message/rfc822 .mhtml .mht 
  AddType multipart/related .mhtml .mht .maff .maf 
</IfModule>
```